# I have one gridview. I want to use it with different tables. One at a time

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I am working on asp.net gridview (WEB.UI.Contorl).
I want to use one gridview only. When a button is clicked,
gridview1 should be filled by table1.
When second button is clicked,
gridview1 should be filled by table2.

Is this possible..?

Comment: yes you can do that. but what you have tried yet you need to post here.one will solve your query not give you full source.if you are stuck in between somewhere then let us show the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
        Text="Button 1" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" 
        Text="Button 2" />
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
```

in code behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = CallToMethodThatReturnFirstDatatable();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = CallToMethodThatReturnSecondDatatable();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes call a stored procedure: MyProc(@ParamTable, ....) Then in the proc have if statements to choose the table depending on the value of @Param. However this is not a good approach for a number of reasons: Linq will not produce your classes unless you do far more jigery pokery. good learning curve though... As you are using asp net, it is probable you are generating a postback to get the other table, so a respose redirect to another page will have absolutely no overhead to speak of. If you insist on doing it async without a postback then you'll need to make the procedure do something like an insert into a table variable then union the select on the table variable variable with a hard coded row of column variables which are somehow excluded and not returned...